# Is it possible to copy or export file from dropbox to my server directly through iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I'd like to copy file in dropbox to my server directly thorough iOS

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948852/upload-files-from-dropbox-box-account-to-my-server-using-an-iphone-app) but the answer is just a solution how to stream file.

Does anyone know is it possible to copy or export to my server directly?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could generate a link to the file in Dropbox and send that to your server. Your server could then download the file.

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media for how to get a temporary link to a file in Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, correct, if you know, please let me confirm how to generate link. I need to get the file path in iOS app at first. Second, combine it after "https://api.dropbox.com/1/media/auto/". As I understand, the file path cannot  be got from my server. Is that correct?

Comment: My idea is to select file with dropbox chooser in app, then get the file path some way...

Comment: I could implemented. Thanks!

Comment: The Chooser will just return you the URL directly.